# Bootstrap - repeating pattern overlay with background color jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a repeating background image over my rebecca-purple background color for my jumbotron. I know I'm doing something wrong, just don't know what it is. Here's the code:

```
.jumbotron {
background-color: rebeccapurple;
color: white;
width: auto;
height: 350px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
position: relative;
display: block;
font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.jumbotron::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: url(\images\bg_images\maze_white.png) repeat center center;
z-index: -1;
}
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: shouldn't your maze be over the purple? z-index:-1 puts it below. Probably you want your :after to have the purple background, and the jumbotron to have the maze.

Comment: @Tesseract - The problem is no effect. I tried swapping the bg-s around per solution below but to no avail. Just get a purple jumbotron with nothing written on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your maze is behind the jumbotron due to z-index:-1. What you need to do is swap the backgrounds around, like in this fiddle http://jsbin.com/tekefobive/edit?css,output

```
.jumbotron {
background-image:url('pattern');
...
}
.jumbotron:after{
background:purple;
z-index:-1;
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but now the entire jumbotron is just purple, no text.

Comment: @n0de in the fiddle you see you can add text no problem, just look at this : http://jsbin.com/yigejisohu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @n0de np, if you feel like this answer helped you, upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try This
.jumbotron {
background: url("IMAGE PATH") rebeccapurple repeat center center;
color: white;
width: auto;
height: 350px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
position: relative;
display: block;
font-family: FontAwesome;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but still didn't work. It has everything except the background pattern.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.